# Replacing text within a long URL using regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am trying to setup a htaccess redirect, but I need some help with the writing regex expression. Here s what I am trying to get to:

`Before: example.com/[wildcard1]/9-3/[wildcard2]/ref/[wildcard3]/[wildcard4]`

`After: example.com/[wildcard1]/wis/9-3/[wildcard2]/ref/[wildcard3]/[wildcard4]`

Comment: so you're adding wis in between and this is same for all other strings?

Comment: That's correct. Trying to Wis in that specific spot

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `^([^\/]+)(\/9-3\/[^\/]+\/ref\/[^\/]+\/.+)$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/34L5GG/1)

Comment: I tweaked your answer to account for a slash before [wildcard1]. I tried using in my line in my htaccess file, but it is not forwarding, although it works in the tester:

`RewriteRule ^(\/[^\/]+)(\/9-3\/[^\/]+\/ref\/[^\/]+\/.+)$ $1\/wis$2 [L]`

Comment: Try changing it to `RewriteRule "^/([^/]+)(/9-3/[^/]+/ref/[^/]+/.+)$" "/$1/wis$2"`

Comment: try adding `[L,NC,NE]` at the end